# cordova Manifest merger failed

Tags: android, cordova

when we are trying to build android using cordova phone-gap this error will occurs

```
:mergeDebugResources
:processDebugManifest D:\Android\ThePlug\platforms\android\AndroidManifest.xml:27:9-31 Error:
    Attribute meta-data#android.support.VERSION@value value=(25.3.1) from [com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1] AndroidManifest.xml:27:9-31
    is also present at [com.android.support:support-v4:26.0.0-alpha1] AndroidManifest.xml:27:9-38 value=(26.0.0-alpha1).
    Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:value"' to <meta-data> element at AndroidManifest.xml:25:5-27:34 to override.
See http://g.co/androidstudio/manifest-merger for more information about the manifest merger.
:processDebugManifest FAILED
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':processDebugManifest'.

  > Manifest merger failed : Attribute meta-data#android.support.VERSION@value val
  >   ue=(25.3.1) from [com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1] AndroidManifest.xml:2
  >   7:9-31 is also present at [com.android.support:support-v4:26.0.0-alpha1] Androi
  >   dManifest.xml:27:9-38 value=(26.0.0-alpha1).Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:value"' to  element a
  >   t AndroidManifest.xml:25:5-27:34 to override.

Comment: I am getting the same error, don't think its related to the recent ionic CLI updates, but error occurred for me once I installed UA cordova plugin.

Comment: when we remove [facebook4](https://github.com/mpk2/cordova-plugin-facebook4) plugin its working properly for me.

Comment: did you try adding tools:replace before removing the plugin?

Comment: no i didn't do anythings

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Remove the facebook4 plugin and reinstall the old version 1.7.4

```
cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-facebook4

cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-facebook4@1.7.4 --save --variable APP_ID="<myid>" --variable APP_NAME="<myname>"
```

It works for me.

[Source](https://github.com/jeduan/cordova-plugin-facebook4/issues/507#issuecomment-304472481)

Comment: @Kenin I'm facing same problem but my plugin is different,
https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications

Comment: I've two plugin using in project phonegap plugin push and https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications so both requests different support library version that's the issue and yes tried everything to solve that but didn't help

Comment: @Kenin If you installed the version 1.7.4 of cordova-plugin-facebook4, then what is suitable version of "npm install --save @ionic-native/facebook@X.Y.Z ?

Answer (score 19):

I am an ionic user, and can confirm there is a issue with version 1.9.1 of the facebook4 plugin which is causing this.

There are two ways to fix this, one quick workaround, and one solution.

1. To fix it so that you can build straight away, do the following:
   Add the following code to the end of the build.gradle file in platforms/android.

   configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
            def requested = details.requested
            if (requested.group == 'com.android.support') {
                if (!requested.name.startsWith("multidex")) {
                    details.useVersion '25.3.1'
                }
            }
       }
    }
2. A better fix is by using this plugin:
   `cordova plugin add cordova-android-support-gradle-release`, which should sort out any of the dependency issues.

The issue is discussed (at length) here:
https://github.com/jeduan/cordova-plugin-facebook4/issues/507

Comment: using `cordova plugin add cordova-android-support-gradle-release` solve my issue on using both facebook & local-notifications plugins

Comment: After install this plugin, got this error.

com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define
Lcom/google/android/gms/iid/zzc;

Comment: Solved for me too with cordova plugin add cordova-android-support-gradle-release --variable ANDROID_SUPPORT_VERSION=25.+  . 
For phonegap build: 

<gap:plugin name="cordova-android-support-gradle-release" source="npm">
    <param name="ANDROID_SUPPORT_VERSION" value="25.+" />
  </gap:plugin>